# what is the proper way to release objects in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, release

I have to confirm with something.
I am releasing my objects in this way.

```
[lblTotalQty, lblTotalAmt, imgEmptyBag, lblEmptyBagMsg release];
```

is this not a proper way?

Please guide me.

Comment: Whoa, neat, never seen anyone use a comma separated list of identifiers to send a single message to... neat.

Comment: So you mean this is not a proper way. and we cant do like this?

Comment: @Steve:  it would be neat if it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the ***how***, You release objects by sending the release message:

```
[myObject release];
```

Never seen the comma-syntax before, and someone suggested only the last object is sent the message (Can anyone confirm this?)

Regarding the ***when***, that's a long story and I recommend you read Apple's docs on the subject;
you could start [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH).

Basically, **you must keep track of object ownership** to avoid having two parties deallocate the same object twice, or conversely, never.

Sounds cumbersome at first, but it's a very good practice in terms of software design; This ownership hierarchy brings meaningful structure to your code.

Alternatively, **IF** you are coding for the Mac, you can use Garbage Collection. Also, if you are coding for iOS 5.0+ and are starting a new project, you can take advantage of the new ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) functionality, which is basically Manual Reference Counting code auto-generated by the compiler: The Best of Both Worlds.

Answer (score 6):

Comma operators will discard all expressions except the last so your statement will in effect become

```
[lblEmptyBagMsg release];
```

So you shouldn't release objects in the way you've indicated in the question. Do them individually i.e. call release on each object separately.

Comment: +1 Thanks to you I actually learned something by reading this thread LOL. There is a reason I've never seen the crazy comma separated list of identifiers before!

Comment: But Deepak I have a question on this.
If we can define variables and can create IBOutlet and can define properties and can synthasize then Wy we can't release in this way?

Comment: Because I am creating IBOutlet in this way

Comment: Comma in those cases acts as a separator rather than an operator ([see this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator)). It depends on the grammar of the language and I believe Objective-C doesn't define it to be a separator.

Answer (score 1):

Its really hard to tell what you're asking here because you give no context.

For one thing, I've never seen anyone use a comma separated list of identifiers to send a single message to, as you do in your example... but I suppose that's not the point of the question.

With the exception of using autorelease pools, sending the `release` message to an object is the **only** way of releasing them.

The confusion with releasing object is usually more a question of "when" not "how". Everyone knows "how" (call `release`). The bigger question is usually "when should I be releasing or retaining an object".